# "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC", but this platform could not be found

Tags: netbeans, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I have this problem with netbeans where I am trying to run an old project that has this emulator. I hit resolve, but it asks me to find the java platform for it.

```
Problem: The project uses the Java Platform called "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC", but this platform was not found.
Solution: Click Resolve and create new platform called "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC".
```

some pictures of what I am seeing:

[image: img844.imageshack.us/img844/5881/capturevbx.jpg] 
[image]

Any help appreciated,

Ted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all just confirm Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC is installed in your system or not.

if it is installed then when you are pressing resolve problem, add platform and select your installed WTK path. it will solve your problem.

There is other approach also. Even if you didn't installed WTK, netbeans having its own emulator. so in project properties there is configuration menu in which you can select available emulator and profile.

you can solve your problem by any of the approach.

Comment: I try but the stupid "finish" button is still disabled, and my WTK folder is in: C:\WTK2.5.2 which I point to ofcourse

Comment: some pictures of what I am seeing:
http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/5881/capturevbx.jpg
http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7688/capture2gz.jpg

Comment: oh dear you have selected wrong option.
select second option Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator.

Comment: @Flethuseo, Dont select `Java ME CDC Platform Emulator`. You have to select `Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator.` Follow the **Mihir** steps.